# Find $(f^{-1})'(a) = f(x) = 2x^3 + 3x^2+7x+4, a=4 $

Tags: calculus

Find $(f^{-1})'(a) = f(x) = 2x^3 + 3x^2+7x+4, a=4 $

How do I go about solving a problem like this? What are the steps?

Comment: Hint: Consider $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and differentiate. And please show self effort.

Comment: Are you saying that $f(x)=2x^3+3x^2+7x+4$, and you want to find $f^{-1}(a)$ where $a=4$? That is not actually what you wrote!

Comment: I wish to have the steps since I do not know how to go about solving.

Comment: You did not answer my question, so I still don't know what you want. Therefore I cannot possibly show you the steps. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Rory Daulton I am writing the question exactly from the book.

Comment: Then the book is badly written. If we are to take your question literally, then just substitute $a=4$ into the formula for $f(x)$. But I doubt that is what is meant, since that makes the derivative and the inverse irrelevant.

Comment: The answer from the book is $ 1/7 $

Comment: @SkakaZulu: maybe you would write $(f^{-1})'(a), f(x)$, and not $(f^{-1})'(a) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to find $x$  such that $f(x) = 4.$  you know there is exactly one such $x$ because $f$ has an inverse. by trial and error, you find that $x = 0.$  so $f$  sends $0$  to $4.$  the slope of $f$  at $x = 0$ is $f'(0) = 7.$  therefore the slope of $f^{-1}$ at the point $y = 4$ is $\left(f^{-1}\right)'(4) = \frac17,$  the reciprocal of the slope of $f$ at the point $x = 0.$